# Consistent missing packet only when flood pinging

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ping, packet

I've been having one packet consistently dropping when initiating a flood ping in ubuntu

[image]

I'll toss out that one with 2 dropped packets as randomness, is there something going on here within the network stack?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Because you are **flood** pinging, the last ping sent is almost never going to complete.